# Http route without parameters and a point inside the route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently creating a webservice using ApiController classes. Due to some restrictions I have to put a Point in the route itself (terminal.journalentry). And use this as the base URL. Thus:

```
http://localhost:59684/terminal.journalentry
```

as example for a call.  Now though I've run into Problems.

When I use the following code with this call: http://localhost:59684/terminal.journalentry it works without a hitch.

```
public class JournalController : ApiController
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("terminal.journalentry/{id}")]
        public void WriteJournalEntry(int id)
        {

        }
}
```

Though I Need to use the method without any Parameters involved. But when I try the following:

```
public class JournalController : ApiController
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("terminal.journalentry")]
        public void WriteJournalEntry()
        {

        }
}
```

With the call being: http://localhost:59684/terminal.journalentry
I get:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Now my question is: What is wrong there and what Needs to be done in order to use the above URL without running into Errors?

Edit as it was asked what the Content of Routes.config is:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs has only the following Content inside  Register: `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: How are you registering your api routes in routes config?

Comment: @ProtectLifeSaveForests edited the question

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you add a trailing slash without an ID?

Comment: @CraigH  nope the same error (was one of the first things I had tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to configure a handler to ignore the ".journalentry".
Usually anything with a fullstop is considered a file, and I imagine this is happening here.

In the web.config for your API, try and find the following section:
`<system.webServer>`
`<handlers>`

And add a handler definition:

```
<add name="JournalEntryExtensionHandler" path="*.journalentry*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

You might need to play around a bit with the path wildcard settings.
When I've done this previously the URL *ended* with a filename so the path was "*.jpg" for example.

Comment: No playing around needed. That did it. Interesting. I feared something in that direction (although not file more like interpreted as offsite url or something like that). But I guess the file interpretation is head on there.  Tnx