# Web API routes that use URLs as parameters no longer working when period included

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

We have been using `HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute` with routes that use URLs as parameters and it has **been working fine for years**.

```
//load image from remote server
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "remote-image",
    routeTemplate: "rimage/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "WebApiClient", action = "rimage" }
);
```

Recently we upgraded few 3rd party NuGet packages that also **upgraded dependency packages**. After that this particular route template is not responding the requests that contain period.

For instance **this works**: `https://my.domain.com/rimage/remote/domain/name/some-image`

But **this does not**:
`https://my.domain.com/rimage/remote/domain/name/some-image.jpg`

What can I add to the template to make sure period can be used?

Comment: This might be relevant still: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310187/asp-net-mvc-route-ids-with-a-period

Comment: @rbonestell but it has been working without the need of updating web.config?

Comment: My answer to this question might also be helpful, although you still have to add to the config. Essentially it boils down to "anything containing a period is considered a file" and you need to tell the request handler to ignore it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111209/http-route-without-parameters-and-a-point-inside-the-route/52116927#52116927

Comment: @CraigH yes that answer saved us.